# Change div bg color

Tags: html, css

i created a main div and split-ted into two css code

```
#main { background-color:#FFFFFF; width:1000px;}
#left {  width:750px; float:left }
#right {  width:250px; float:right }
```

but background color does not changes , when i changed it to

```
#main {  width:1000px;}
#left { background-color:#FFFFFF; width:750px; float:left }
#right { background-color:#000000; width:250px; float:right }
```

it works but when height changes it looks boring i want to change the background color of whole main div.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? All your first example does is set the background to white.

Comment: Can you put together a jsFiddle?

Comment: What's your html? Do your `#left` and `#right` elements exist in your mark-up?

Answer (score 0):

what about if your main div gets a

```
#main {
    min-height:100px;
    max-height:100px;
}
```

it needs a height to display background-color

if its not working show the html part please

Answer (score 0):

Without the html this is just a guess, but I think your problem is that the div#main has a height of 0. This happens because the floating divs inside are no longer part of the document flow. Try setting a height on the main div, this should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Add following rule

> #main:after { content: " "; display: block; overflow: hidden; clear: both; height: 0; }

It will clear floats and make the container as high as the highest column inside.